# Check whether characters in a string are delimited by a space [Python]

Tags: python, string

Let's say I have a string `a = 31 4 5 + +` and a string `b = 31 4 5 ++`. I need to check that all numbers and operators in the string are delimited by at least one white space. Therefore, string a is correct, string b incorrect. `c = 31 4 5+ +` is also incorrect. Is there a way how to check for this? I could not come up with anything reasonable.

Comment: Consider using RegEx check https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

Answer (score 0):

You can check it through following steps -

- Break string into list using `.split()`
- Check whether items in list whose length is more than 1 is numeric or not.

Code snippet:

```
def is_valid_string(st, delimiter = ' '):
  lst = st.split(delimiter)  # create list of chars separated by space
  for item in lst:
    if len(item) > 1 and not item.isdigit():
      return False
  return True
```

In case if you are considering float numbers you can use `item.replace('.','',1).isdigit()`

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do would be splitting the strings by the whitespaces into "words", so something like `words = a.split()` (`split`'s delimitor is a whitespace by default so no need for arguments)

I'm guessing you're only gonna use integers or floats and a set of operators like adding, substraction, multiplication and division, so one thing that you could do is check if you can cast the words into numbers with `int` or `float` and if you can't, check if the word is in your operators set, so something like:

```
a = "31 4 5 + +"
operators = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]

# Every string is valid by default
valid = True

words = a.split()  # ["31", "4", "5", "+", "+"]

for word in words:
    # try to cast word into a number
    try:
        float(word)
    except:
        # if you can't, check if it's an operator
        if word not in operators:
            valid = False #if it's not, the string isn't valid

if valid:
    print("String is valid")
else:
    print("String is not valid")
```

More complex stuff like equations and variables is obviously more difficult to code.

EDIT: python's `isdigit()` checks if a string is a number and it is more simple than a try block for casting the string, but it doesn't check for floats, which won't be valid. (you could still replace decimal points by numbers)

Answer (score 0):

Try use regex `^((\d+|[+*/-])(\s+|$))+$`. It matches more or more items, each of which is either a number (`\d+`) or an operator (`[+*/-]`), followed by either one or more spaces (`\s+`) or the end of string (`$`). The `^` at the beginning and (`$`) at the end force the regex match the whole string. Example:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = '31 4 5 + +'
>>> b = '31 4 5 ++'
>>> c = '31 4 5+ +'
>>> print(re.match(r'^((\d+|[+*/-])(\s+|$))+$', a))
<re.Match object; span=(0, 10), match='31 4 5 + +'>
>>> print(re.match(r'^((\d+|[+*/-])(\s+|$))+$', b))
None
>>> print(re.match(r'^((\d+|[+*/-])(\s+|$))+$', c))
None
```